# grab console output to dom with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, console, variable-assignment

this is my html file

```js
<script>

var output = console.dir(location);
document.write(output);

</script>
```

and iam trying to assign console output to a variable "output" 
but its output is just

```
undefined
```

what i need is somewhat like,

```json
{
  "ancestorOrigins": {
    "0": "https://www.google.com"
  },
  "href": "about:blank",
  "origin": "null",
  "protocol": "about:",
  "host": "",
  "hostname": "",
  "port": "",
  "pathname": "blank",
  "search": "",
  "hash": ""
}
```

output would be a json or array
but it wouldn't be undefined 
or do i have to use try & catch or something like that to get its output

Comment: console functions have no return value. Mayhap something like `var output = JSON.stringify(window.location, 4)` is what you seek.

Comment: This is not possible. What exactly do plan to do with the output?

Comment: I've tried `JSON.stringify` , but it is not what i need, it wont work if i use `window` or `document` or _`THREE` from external file like three.js_  instead of `window.location` @Lain

Comment: In that case you will have to loop through all entries of an object on your own and define the rules as you want/need them on your own. Something like `Object.entries(window).forEach((entry) => console.log(entry))`.

Comment: Yes, it won't work for objects with cyclic references. Again, what you are you actually trying to achieve here? Knowing that would likely increase the chances that we can help you.